# Problems connecting to mysql on debian, error 2002

Tags: mysql, linux, debian

I'm trying to run a mysql connection, and I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to connect to mysql: (2002) Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have been checking on other forums etc, and yes i checked if mysql server is running, and yes it is running ok,no portblocking, but what i see strage is that i dont ahve mysql.sock in my /var/lib/mysql directory.
I appreciate any sign of help.

Comment: Is connection error happening while trying from terminal or from the application level ?

Comment: Is happening when I'm trying to start my MTA:SA server with screen package.

Comment: Make sure that that the mysql service is running.. in debian you can simply kickoff as `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` or `sudo service mysqld start` and then try to login from terminal as `mysql -u username -p`, from application level it may be due to host `mysql -u username -h localhost -p` try it as `mysql -u username -h 127.0.0.1 -p`. And last make sure that /tmp folder is having write permission.

Comment: when i try to start it , it says it is already running, no host problems, and tmp have drwxrwxrwt